# How to test whether the absolute change of two paired samples different from zero

Tags: paired-comparisons, paired-data

I have two paired samples.

$\text{Group 1}: X_1,X_2, ...,X_n$
$\text{Group 2}: Y_1,\;Y_2,...,\;Y_n$.

$(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2), ..., (X_n, Y_n)$ are paired respectively.

The null hypothesis is $\mu_{|X-Y|} = 0$,
the alternative hypothesis is $\mu_{|X-Y|} > 0$

What is the appropriate test for this purpose?

Comment: Like a (two-tailed) paired t-test, Wilcoxon signed rank test or sign test, for example? What aspect of the distribution of the difference are you most interested in?

Comment: I am interested if the mean of the absolute difference significantly different from zero or not.

Comment: If you have data that's roughly normalish, I'd suggest a paired-t-test. If you don't, there are a variety of choices, but if the differences aren't too skew, I'd lean toward a permutation test.

Comment: Could you remind me how permutation test can be used here

Comment: Sure I'll expand my comments to an answer.

Comment: Your present null hypothesis makes no sense. Even when $X$ and $Y$ are from the same population $E(|X-Y|)$ is only $0$ when the common variance is $0$. That is, when $X-Y$ is *always* $0$. A single $x_i\neq y_i$ is sufficient to cause rejection. Please clarify further.

Comment: try the following R code, you will see a single $x_i \neq y_i$ is not sufficient to cause rejection.  > foo = c(1:9,9)
> goo = c(1:10)
>  t.test(foo,goo,paired=T). The p.value also depends on the variation of the differences.

Comment: That's because you're not testing the hypothesis in your question, but a different hypothesis. $|X-Y|$ is always $\geq 0$. Pretty much the only test procedure that makes sense is "reject if any $x_i\neq y_i$", because if even one pair is unequal, the chance the null is true is $0$.

Comment: I need to conduct this test for a few different data sets. And I am interested in ranking the p-values. In other words, I am interested in seeing which data set has the most evidence to show the difference between the profile of the two paired samples.

Comment: What you want doesn't change the problem with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see your point now. Right, the chance that $\mu=0$ under null hypothesis is zero.

Comment: So, maybe I didn't form the null hypothesis correctly. What do you think the null hypothesis should be, if I want to test how much the profile change is between two paired samples.  By profile change, I mean the increase or decrease of the value for every paired data points.

Comment: If you're really interested in testing whether the mean difference ($\mu_{X-Y}$) is nonzero, a tendency for  X-Y to be sometimes large negative and sometimes large positive is simply a situation of large variance. It makes it harder to detect whether the means differ, which does reduce power. There's not really a way around that. You just test the hypothesis you care about, the best way you can. I can't tell you your hypothesis, but note *carefully* that hypotheses are about populations, not *data*.

Comment: If you want to test individual pairs of points, you're going to have almost no power.

Comment: Good point. I really appreciate!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you specify an interest in the alternative $\mu_D\neq 0$, I'll discuss several   possibilities:

1) paired t-test: suitable if the differences are approximately normal. Moderately tolerant of non-normality.

2) Wilcoxon signed rank test: effectively a permutation test on the mean of the signed ranked differences. Assumes symmetry of the differences (and under that assumption, works as a test for the mean difference being zero).

3) Sign test. Does not assume symmetry, but is not a test for the mean difference being zero if you don't have symmetry. Since it tends to have lower power unless the tails are very heavy, if you're going to assume symmetry you'd usually be better off with (2).

4) permutation test. This has the same assumptions as (2) - independence, symmetry of differences, but it has better power at the normal than (2) (so if you're really having trouble working out which of (1) or (2) to do, you should probably do (4) instead. If your tails are heavier than normal, say logistic-ish, you might be slightly better off with (2) from a power point of view. On the other hand, the loss of power *at* the normal if you do (2) is surprisingly small, so there's not all that much to worry about either way.

The permutation test works as follows:

If the null is true and the distribution of differences is symmetric, then the differences would be as likely to have one sign as the other - under the null hypothesis, the signs are arbitrary.

So you can generate pseudosamples by taking the absolute differences and giving each one a random sign.

For each pseudosample you calculate some test statistic which will tend to be unusual compared to the null case (i.e. is sensitive to the alternative). One example is the sum of the signed differences.

If $n$ is the number of differences, then there are $2^n$ such sets of signs. If $2^n$ is tractable (say $n<20$ or so), you can compute all possible arrangements of signs.

If $n$ is too big to find them all, you can randomly sample the sets of signs (making it a randomization test rather than a permutation test).

Either way, you end up with a distribution for the test statistic. You find where your sample statistic lies in the distribution. If it's in either extreme tail (say the top of bottom $n\alpha/2$ values, you would reject the null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, as I mentioned in the question, I am interested in the absolute change of these two groups. The tests in your answer are all used for testing the equality of the two group means. In the case that half of samples are increased and the other half of the samples are decreased, a test for testing the equality of two group means will probably give a non-significant p-value. However, I suppose if we test the ABSOLUTE CHANGE, the result will be very likely significant.

Comment: Your original phrasing was ambiguous. It suggested to me that you were after a difference in either direction - I even asked you to confirm the kind of thing with my initial comment, to which your response merely repeated the same somewhat ambiguous information (a simple 'no, I don't mean that' would have been more help), again leaving me guessing. Please edit your question to include an algebraic definition (in terms of what you have measured) of what you want to compare, and a clear statement of your null and alternative hypotheses, and I will modify my answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare mean deviation from the mean, as a way of comparing spreads, is that right? Can you define your variables, clarify how many there are and make explicit the comparison, please?

Comment: I apologize for confusion. The original question is edited. Thank you!